# Create a field in a Mongoose Schema that is a reference to other fields in the same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So that if the original fields are modified, the copied field changes too.

Pseudo-code example :

```
userSchema = {
    firstName: {type: String},
    lastName: {type: String},
    displayName: firstName + ' ' + lastName
}
```

Is something like this possible ?

**EDIT:** I need to make request based on that field, so I can't just concat the fields when i retrieve them.

Comment: Usually, you would concat the fields in your DAO. This way, you'd reduce data redundancy while still getting the same results.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to make a request based on that field ? Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'll edit my question.

Comment: You could create a text index over first name and last name..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the hooks http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```
userSchema = {
    firstName: {type: String},
    lastName: {type: String},
    displayName: {type: String}
}

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.displayName = this.username+' '+this.lastName;
    next();
});
```